# MySQL Setting multiple versions of data under one unique name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on creating a php form that stores project data under a unique project name, and then storing that data into a MySQL database.

For example:

**Project Name: Proj001**

**Max racing speed (m/s): 80**

However,  I want to be able to add in newer versions of a project while keeping the older versions of project data.  If possible, I would like to create an option so the user may designate a project version as the "default" project to show when users are using a search engine to find projects.  They could switch the default project that shows up on a search engine with some other method.

For example:

**Project Name: Proj001**

**Max racing speed (m/s): 85**

*Proj001 already exists! Make this default? Yes/No*

(If the user selects yes, upon a search of Proj001 the max racing speed will return 85.  If the user selects no, upon a search of Proj001 the max racing speed will return 80).

Is it possible to do something like this with PHP/MySQL?  I'm not looking for any code but for a possible concept of how to make it work using the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in MySQL that says that a row needs a unique identifier. It is certainly common practice to do so but is by no means required.

You could definitely implement your example. You would obviously need a boolean field `default` that could be updated whenever the user inputs a value. Just run a `SELECT` query from PHP when you gather the user input, if there are results prompt for the default update, otherwise just add it and be on your way.

The problem you most often run in to without a unique identifier is updating a row. Let's take your example but say the user types in 80 mph again as the max speed. If you add that row, you now have two rows that have `Proj001` and `80` as fields. How is SQL supposed to know which one to update? You can always add a `LIMIT 1` to your query to only update 1 row but this should at least provide some insight as to why unique fields are commonly used.

Comment: I would still have the unique identifier so you would be able to differentiate between the two records.

Comment: thanks for the help.  If you don't mind me asking...in MySQL when creating the table I have columns "project" and "speed".  If I want people to name their default based on same project name, do I just enable the default option under the project name column?  And then if a new project with the same name is input, I can prompt the person to make it default over the other project with the same name.  Is that how it works?

Comment: @user2562568 I'm not sure I'm totally understanding your question but you will need to add a new column to contain the default status. So 3 columns: `project`, `speed`, and `isDefault`. That help?

Comment: ohh okay I see what you mean now.  I was confused because in the mysql table-creation, there's a column that is labeled "Default", and I thought implementing your method involved invoking this pre-made default column.  But yeah I'll just make my own "isDefault" column.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible.

What you will need is a field to contain the default value along with an auto incrementing id field.

Do your insert as normal.

For your set default function would do this (pseudo code).

```
 function setDefault($project_name, $id){
       $id = quoteAndSanatize($id);
       $project_name = quoteAndSanatize($project_name);
       $db->runQuery("UPDATE project set default = (id = $id) where name = $project_name");
 }
```

This will ensure that for a given project name only one default exists.